# C# How to pause a video with button click (webBrowser)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need help with a small thing.
I try to pause a YouTube video which is embedded in a `webBrowser1` object with a `ButtonClick`.

How would I do that? Here's my code:

```cs
string url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT35P_lrCCg";
string html = "<html><head>";
html += "<meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>";
html += "<iframe id='video' src= 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{0}' width='600' height='300' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
html += "</body></html>";
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = string.Format(html, url.Split('=')[1]);
```

Also , I have another `Button` called `close`.
Its operation is to hide a `Panel` in which  the video is played, but hiding that panel does not stop the video and it keeps playing.

I made a portfolio -
[MyPortfolio](https://itzplayz0001.github.io/Portfolio/)

Comment: Have you checked all/any of [those posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+youtube+pause+video+site:stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: Yea no hope, I checked :(

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls

Comment: `var playElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON").OfType<HtmlElement>().FirstOrDefault(elm => elm.GetAttribute("className").Equals("ytp-play-button ytp-button")); playElement?.InvokeMember("click");`

Comment: @Jimi It doesn't fix it